# embeded HTML doesn't show on react page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to ad some gofundme donation buttons on a react page but it doesn't even show on screen.

```js
const Donation = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="gfm-embed" data-url="https://www.gofundme.com/f/theyre-the-real-victims/widget/large/"></div>
            <script defer src="https://www.gofundme.com/static/js/embed.js"></script>
        </div>
    )
}
    
export default Donation
```

I have neve done anything like this before. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

React uses `innerHTML` to add elements to the DOM. `innerHTML` disables execution of `script` tags.

> HTML5 specifies that a  tag inserted with innerHTML should not execute.

So, the recommended way to include `script` tags is via the `useEffect` hook

```js
const Donation = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = "https://www.gofundme.com/static/js/embed.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, []);

    
  return (
   <div>
     <div className="gfm-embed" data-url="https://www.gofundme.com/f/theyre-the-real-victims/widget/large/"></div>
   </div>
  )
};

export default Donation
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'height')